# could not find module 'ember-resources'

Tags: ember.js, modulenotfounderror, ember-controllers

am trying to build an web app with ember and in the process of making a request to server and receiving a response and for that i used resources from ember-resource
yet it always popping the error module not found `ember-resources`

the js code

```
import { use, resource } from 'ember-resources';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';

class RequestState {
  @tracked value;
  @tracked error;

  get isPending() {
    return !this.error && !this.value;
  }
}

export default class RoomselectController extends Controller {
    @service router;

    @use request = resource(({ on }) => {
      const mobile = '123123123';
      const state = new RequestState();
    
      $.ajax({
        url: 'My',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { mobile },
        success: (response) => state.value = response;,
        error: (xhr, status, error) => state.error = `${status}: ${xhr.statusText}`,
      });

      return state;
    });

    get result() {
      return this.request.value || [];
    }

}
```

i installed ember-resource using
`ember install ember-resources`
also done `npm install ember-resources`

still showing the same module not found errro what to do?

Comment: did you restart your dev server? ctrl+c the `ember s` that's running and run `ember s` again?

Comment: yeah did that.. even restarted my computer

Comment: does ember-resources show up under `dependencies` in the same package.json that your ember app uses?

do you have ember-auto-import@v2+ installed?

Comment: yeah i have both ember-resources : 5.2.1 and ember-auto-import : 2.4.2 listed on dev-dependencies

Comment: if you move them to `dependencies` instead of `devDependencies`, re-install, and re-run `ember s`, does anything behave any different?

Comment: nope.. still showing could not find module `ember-resources`

Comment: does this behavior occur in a fresh ember app? can you post a reproduction repo? what differences do you have been a reproduction repo and your app?

Comment: i followed the question and answer from the stack thread [link](stackoverflow.com/questions/73428484/couldnt-render-a-json-array-from-servlet-in-ember-js) and it seems he is having the same module import error

Comment: Wanted to provide some example apps that use that library, in case they help -- https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/polaris-starter and https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/limber/tree/main/frontend 

To debug an installation issue, I'll need a reproduction repo on GitHub or similar. 